# Spring Boot MongoDb repository findAll() returns empty list

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application running against a MongoDb instance.

When calling the findAll() method from MongoRepository, the repository returns an empty list, whereas I have one document in the collection.

The connection to the database at startup works fine.
I have checked documentation and do not know what the issue is coming from.

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

}
```

Service:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUser {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws Exception {

        // 1: Initialisation
        log.info("[ getAllUsers ] Start");
        List<User> response = new ArrayList<User>();

        // 2: call Dao
        try {
            log.debug("Calling user Dao to select all users");
            response = userDao.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(Constants.COMMENT_SELECTION_ERROR, e);
            throw new Exception(Constants.COMMENT_SELECTION_ERROR, e);
        }

        // 3: Cloture
        log.debug("Response: count of users :{} ", response.size());
        log.info("[ getAllUsers ] End :: Success");
        return response;
    }
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/user")
public class UserApiController {

    @Autowired
    private IUser sUser;

    @ApiOperation(value = "getAllUsers", response = ResponseEntity.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "selection successful", response = User.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Required parameter does not exist or is not in the expected format", response = User.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource", response = User.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 406, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found", response = User.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        log.info("[ getAllUsers ] Start");
        List<User> responseListUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            responseListUsers = sUser.getAllUsers();
            log.info("[ getAllUsers ] End :: Success");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListUsers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception se) {
            log.error("[ getAllUsers ] End :: ERROR", se.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListUsers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
@ApiModel(value = "User", description = "User Model")
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    String id;
    /**
     * The user name
     *
     * @param name: The user name
     * @return the current value of the name
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "name", required = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    /**
     * The user address
     *
     * @param address: The user address
     * @return the current value of the address
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "address", required = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String address;
    /**
     * The user phone
     *
     * @param phone: The user phone
     * @return the current value of the phone
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "phone", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.PHONE_FORMAT)
    private String phone;
    /**
     * The user job
     *
     * @param job: The user function
     * @return the current value of the user job
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "job", required = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String job;
    /**
     * The name of the agency to which the user is attached
     *
     * @param agency: The name of the agency to which the user is attached
     * @return the current value of the agency
     */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "agency", required = true)
    @DBRef
    private Agency agency;
}
```

Collection :
[image: User document]

The logs show nothing interesting, when I hit http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/getAllUsers , I just get following logs :

> 2021-03-31 15:51:51.023  INFO 19804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.airbnb.controller.UserApiController  : [ getAllUsers ] Start

> 2021-03-31 15:51:51.025  INFO 19804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.airbnb.service.impl.UserServiceImpl  : [ getAllUsers ] Start

> 2021-03-31 15:51:51.035  INFO 19804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.airbnb.service.impl.UserServiceImpl  : [ getAllUsers ] End :: Success

> 2021-03-31 15:51:51.037  INFO 19804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.airbnb.controller.UserApiController  : [ getAllUsers ] End :: Success

Comment: Use `@Service` instead of `@Component`. And your models shows `String id;` But in the database it's an `ObjectId`> If u need String then you can use `@Id String _id=UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `@javax.persistence.Id` in your model class, as:

```java
@ApiModel(value = "User", description = "User Model")
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    String id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added Id annotation from org.springframework.data.annotation.Id, still does not work after restart

Comment: I have typical architecture with Controller calling Service calling Repository. I have added those in the post. The logs show nothing interesting, no exception thrown but list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Databasewise my User document was not pointing to a specific Agency via an Id.
It looks like that when you define a Model containing an @DbRef property pointing to another Model, the document in the database must be correctly populated with an id pointing to the parent entity, otherwise the findAll() method will ignore this document.
Now it works.

[image: User pointing to Agency through Id]